# Has there ever been a Star Wars / Star Trek crossover?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, crossovers

Obviously, both Star Wars and Star Trek have been massive cultural phenomenon, both widely regarded as being some of the best and most influential sci-fi. Because of their popularity, both series have seen a large amount of spin off material: Books, Comics, TV shows and Movies, video games, everything.

My question is: **Is there any official content in which the two universes  cross over?**

Comment: Just in internet debates on which is better.

Comment: Do easter eggs count? Like when R2D2 is seen floating in space during a battle scene in Star Trek Into Darkness. Or when the Millennium Falcon is seen during a Borg fight scene.

Comment: Nothing canon, but if you search a couple of fanfic sites, I'll bet there's loads XD

Comment: @DisturbedNeo There was a pretty good one posted to Usenet back in the time of ST:TNG.

Comment: Sometime between "never" and "over the dead bodies of everyone at Lucasfilm and Paramount"; http://www.eonline.com/videos/250839/will-there-be-a-star-trek-and-star-wars-crossover

Comment: No never, unless you consider youtube cannon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbJ-y6BWfUc

Comment: There was some speculation about this a while back (http://nationalreport.net/jj-abrams-planning-star-wars-star-trek-crossover-film/) but I don't know if that's reliable information. My two cents is that such a crossover would be even more painful to watch than the Simpsons/Family Guy crossover was.

Comment: Does The Simpsons episode where someone mixes up Star Wars and Star Trek count?

Comment: the closest you could get, imo, is if we assumed that the Indiana Jone and Star Trek share the same universe. If we take that as an axiom, then, pre-Disney canon, there was an Indiana Jones / Han Solo + Chewbacca web comic crossover in which the Falcon crashed landed on prehistoric earth, Han died and his skeleton is watched over by Chewbacca. Jones comes across the wreck and is observed by a hiding Chewie. But even in this case, Trek and Star Wars aren't really coming into contact w/ each other so #itsastrech

Comment: Star Trek is our future. Star Wats is the far past “a long time ago in a galaxy far away”. It’d be hard to figure out how to do a crossover

Comment: There is quite a bit of fan-fiction on the topic. For example https://www.fanfiction.net/StarTrek-The-Next-Generation_and_Star-Wars_Crossovers/7/8/?&srt=1&r=103&p=2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As yet, **there has not been a Star Wars/Star Trek crossover in film, TV, comics, toys or any other *licensed* property.**

There have, however, been a considerable number of "easter eggs" that reference the two properties including the appearance of the [Millennium Falcon in Star Trek: First Contact](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/curiosities/milleniumfalcon-firstcontact.jpg) and [R2-D2 appearing in Star Trek (2009)](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/4/4c/R2-D2_cameo_in_Star_Trek.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20091118110032&path-prefix=en)

Comment: Upvoting for the links to the pictures.

Comment: Here is a fun 20min audio narrative with a cross over. Star Trek: The Section 31 Files - Season 1, Ep 9 - https://player.fm/series/star-trek-the-section-31-files/0109-the-section-31-files-distant-shores

Comment: @phillihp - OP was only interested in official content, not fanfic.

Answer (score 0):

### Path 1

*Star Wars* was sold to Disney, the sarlacc from *Star Wars: Return of the Jedi* was mentioned in *Once Upon a Time in Wonderland* "Forget Me Not". *...Wonderland* is a spin off of *Once Upon a Time*. *Once Upon a Time* "The Stranger" had a quick shot of an Oceanic Airlines plane with the same logo as seen on *Lost*.

(We are now entering the J.J. Abrams TV universe.)

*Lost* crossed over with *Alias* twice. The first time was in *Alias* "Authorized Personnel Only" (part 2) when Driveshaft from *Lost* was mentioned; the second time was *Alias* "A Clean Conscience" when the flight from *Lost* was mentioned.

*Alias* introduced a drink called Slusho! A Slusho! beverage was seen on *Star Trek* (2009), which was directed by J.J. Abrams.

That is the most concrete series of links I can come up with for you. J.J. Abrams was involved heavily in *Lost*, *Alias*, and *Star Trek* (2009). *Lost*, *Alias*, and *Once Upon a Time* and its spin-off were on ABC around the same time. ABC is owned by Disney that also owns the *Star Wars* franchise with J.J. Abrams directing *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* and *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*.

### Path 2

This path is very soft, so you can ignore it.

C3PO and R2-D2 appeared on a column in an Egyptian pyramid in *Raiders of the Lost Ark*. One of the shuttle craft in *Star Trek: The Next Generation* "Evolution" is named Indiana Jones. At the time, *Indiana Jones* and *Star Trek* were both owned by Paramount. George Lucas co-wrote the story for *Raiders of the Lost Ark*.

I know this is soft. Other than the previously mentioned appearances of R2-D2 in *Star Trek* (2009) (and *Star Trek Into Darkness*), this is the most direct route. However, be careful with this one. R2-D2 also appeared briefly in *Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen*, and there is an Imperial Shuttle in *Firefly* "Serenity". The last leads down a rabbit hole of space ships appearing in various places where they may not belong.